# SKR 1.4 Turbo - Withhout SD-card reader, bricked?

Tags: marlin, sd, skr-v1.4

Unfortunately and regrettably.

Whilst trying to install and fit an SKR Turbo 1.4 Turbo Motherboard into 3D printer body, I managed to break the SKR 1.4 Turbo Motherboard SD-card reader. The card reader is not flush and protrudes from the board. It peeled the reader from the PCB.

I attempted to fix it without success. I have since removed it from the controller board (the original SD-Card Reader PCB pads are not intact so connecting a new SD-Card Reader in place is not possible)

**Have I bricked my brand new controller board?**

Please can anyone suggest (If possible):

1. Is there a way that this could be rectified in respect to uploading/flashing the Marlin 2 firmware to the SKR 1.4 Turbo
   without the original SD-Card Reader Module?
   *I am under the impression I may be able to use a programmer of some description to upload the firmware?*
2. Installation of a new SD-Card Reader that could be used instead of the built in default SD-Card Reader?
   *I think I would be required to first modify Marlin and then flash the motherboard firmware? Then perhaps be able to connect another SD-Card reader to the motherboard via SPI or alternative e.g wires to the respective pins on the reverse of the board?*

Could somebody kindly point me in the right direction?
I would appreciate some guidance if this indeed possible?

Answer (score 2):

You may get lucky flashing firmware with the STM Cube Programmer, though I haven't tried that.

The [schematic for the SKR 1.4 Turbo](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-V1.3/blob/master/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4/Hardware/BTT%20SKR%20V1.4-SCH.pdf) shows that the relevant pins for the SD card are also accessible via the 2x3 SPI header - except for the P0.27 pin used for "SD DETECT", which you may have to circumvent.

I believe you should be able to use an "SDRamps" module and connect that to the SPI header via jumper cables.

Answer (score 2):

If you are skilled with soldering, you can connect the pins of the SD card reader directly to the pins of the CPU with thin wires. They are small, but it's doable.

Then hot glue all in place to avoid stress on the wires.

Whatever you decide to do, be sure that it will be less convenient than getting a new board, assuming you value your time at least around 10 Euro/dollars per hour...